# How do I properly use INumber in .NET 7 in F#?

Tags: generics, interface, f#, .net-7.0, .net-generic-math

I was reading the following on .NET 7 and [`INumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math):

It gave an example of adding two INumber generic values, which I tried to replicate in F# to no success.

```
let add<'T when 'T :> INumber<'T>>
    (left : 'T) (right: 'T) : 'T =
    left + right
```

This gives "The declared type parameter 'T cannot be resolved at run time.
When I try a different way, to be super clear:

```
let add<'T when 'T :> INumber<'T>>
        (left : 'T) (right: 'T) : 'T =
        INumber<'T>.``+`` left right
```

"INumber<'T'>.`+` is not defined."

Please can someone help me understand how to make this work, and provide the correct format for something like this?

Comment: The first snippet works for me just fine.

Comment: What IDE are you using? What project settings do you have?

Comment: VS 2022, 17.3.6 - I will update now and make a note if this is the issue

Comment: It works now, 17.4 is good. Update your VS version everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [.NET 7 release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.md#visual-studio-compatibility) for .NET 7 support in Visual Studio you need to install 17.4+ version:

> You need Visual Studio 17.4 latest preview to use .NET 7.0 on Windows. On macOS, you need the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac. The C# extension for Visual Studio Code supports .NET 7.0 and C# 11.

Answer (score 1):

As Guru Stron mentioned, the first snippet should work fine. If you want to explicitly access a member of the interface instead (your second snippet), I think it would be:

```ml
let add<'T when 'T :> INumber<'T>>
    (left : 'T) (right: 'T) : 'T =
    'T.op_CheckedAddition(left, right)
```

This syntax is [new in F# 7.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-fsharp-7/#making-working-with-srtps-easier).